# Set CSS width to 100% + right border is missing?

Tags: css, border, html

I set a div's width to 100% of the window. When I apply a border to this div, the right border is cut off. Do I have to perform a box model hack to this?

```css
#textBoxContainer {
  width:100%;
  height:30%;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:99;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-color:#999;
  border: 4px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="textBoxContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest fix in your case is this:

```css
#textBoxContainer {
    height: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #999;
    border: 4px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="textBoxContainer"></div>
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/zxtrN/)

- Remove `width: 100%`.
- To make the `div` fill the screen, instead add `right: 0`.

It's perfectly viable to give an element both a `left` and a `right` (or a `top` and a `bottom`), like we're doing here.

Answer (score 45):

Already has been answered, but I like this solution better. Add this to textBoxContainer:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

It will put the border on the inside of the box.  More info: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Edit - Doesn't work on IE7, but not much does. Here's more on that: [box-sizing support in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909667/box-sizing-support-in-ie7)

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. The accepted answer didn't work for me as I was having the same problem but using width:33.33%.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat related firefox bug
A 100% select dropdown will often be missing its right border (dependent on width of window)
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=924068
No workaround other than to try width: 99%

Comment: I tried width: 99% to solve FF dropdown bug, but it did not help :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181842/missing-border-right-in-select-on-firefox