# Missing border-right in select on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

When I put select into div with width and padding-left, my options have no border on the right. What is more, it happend only if select have width 118px and parent have 15px of padding left! Someone have idea, what is going on?

My simply code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 1000px; padding-left: 15px;">
    <select style="width: 118px;">
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And result:

[image]

Here is a plunker: [click](http://plnkr.co/edit/h72YdsVOZkXZAZBHQNCT?p=preview)

It happend only on firefox on Windows. I tested it on 40.0.2 version

Comment: Looks fine to me. On Win7 in firefox v. 40.0.2. I have used your plunker link.

Comment: Looks fine to me. On Win 10. Latest Firefox.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the screen resolution? I have this problem on 1600x900. When I resize browser window to some size, select looks fine... but on 1600x900 nope...

Comment: There is a [bug report about this case](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=924068)

Comment: There is no trick to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11390432/4431269
source of problem: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=924068

And the good use of GOOGLE !

**Edit:** (source of problem, explained)

After reading the bugreport, i read that it is possible it has something to do with widows.size or resolution. the problem can be fix as explained previous.

Comment: Please explain why though :)

Comment: @MichaelJones already posted the solution and the source but i will please you better :) (a second please)

Comment: @kubut give me a minute.. i will look for you a little deeper.

Comment: @kubut can you try to remove  width: 118px; from the SELECT ELEMENT and applied to OPTION ELEMENT and see if border is missing ?

Comment: Still I have no border... :(

Comment: @kubut i cannot find the bug for me, so i need you to test... remove the width.. no width at all, then hes back ?

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs If I remove width from select everything looks fine. What is more it is enough to change width to 120px. The same situation is with padding-left on parent - when I removed it (and select still has 118px width) - border is coming back.

Comment: @kubut than the problem is found.. when element.width > 100% then border goes away..   add margin: 0; padding: 0 to SELECT ELEMENT and still 118px should show the right-border

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs like that: <select style="width: 118px; padding: 0; margin: 0"> ? Doesn't help. What do you mean about 'element.width > 100%'? Window has ~1500px, div has 1015px and select only 118px width.

Comment: @kubut i'm not good explaining myself in English ;) try this: <select style="width: 20em;> (or 21em, 22em, so on) or this <select style="width: 117px; >

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs 117px works, 119 too. Only 118 is unlucky, but I can't ignore that value (it is set by user). 18em works, 19 nope, 20 yes, 21 yes, 22 nope... It is really weird...

Comment: @kubut it is a bug.. and how so it i set by user ?

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs It is part of multibook viewer, where all elements (including selects) I get define in book's files (json files where are defined images, texts and interactive elements). In this files I have define width of any element, something like: "element" : { "type" : "combo", "width" : "118", "height" : "20", "x" : "10", "y" : "10", "options" : [...], ... }

Comment: Would these styles be applied globally on the html or body tags? Or specifically to the select option elements?

Answer (score -1):

We can place a border-right on the option i.e. **border-right:1px solid grey**.
This way I didn't have to make any adjustments to the width defined.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRVeo.png)

or if you are okay making width adjustments then can set the width to auto for the css of select,i.e. **width:auto**

Comment: Please check how to answer. In Stackoverflow.