# CSS: layout DL as flexible table with paddings

Tags: css

I want to use DL/DT/DD approach to organize my forms. I need to structure them as tables (a column for label and a column for value). The following html+css works fine but till I add margin or padding to dt and/or dd.

```
<html><head>
<style>
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

dt {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
dd {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
</style></head>
<body>
<dl>
  <dt>first name</dt>
  <dd><input />
</dl>
</body></html>
```

If I replace "margin: 0px" in dt's style with "margin: 5px" or the same for padding then dd element jumps on next row.

I need:

- 2-column table layout for DL
- do not use absolute widths (that's because I'm using "50%" as columns' widths)
- add some margin/padding to dt/dd

How to add margin/padding and keep relative widths (50%/50%)?

p.s. I've seen many similar questions about DL and table layout, but my question about combination of dl + table layout + relative widths + paddings. I can get it working with  relative widths or paddings but not both.

Comment: Do you need support for IE <= 7?

Comment: If you want a table, why not use a table?

Comment: @yunzen yes, but I wonder how to do this for modern browsers at least

Comment: @yunzen well, it's all about semantic vs layout. Tables aren't very popular these days :). I wanted to use semantic tags

Comment: Well, tables **are** semantic if you have tabular data in it. And a form _can_ be seen as tabular data

Comment: agreeed, but I have column with property name and column with input control for property value. I think it's not tabular data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to specify the [magical property](http://frontenddevreactions.tumblr.com/post/50110341554/the-first-time-i-heard-about-box-sizing-border-box): [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).  You can then use padding all you want without increasing the width.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X6APE/)

See also:  [box-sizing support in ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10978314/361684)

`box-sizing` addresses padding and borders, but not margins.  If you want to use margin as well, use `calc()` to subtract the margin from the width.  For example, if you want a 5px left margin:

```css
dd {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
}
```

But, `calc()` does not work in IE8 or earlier.

[more on `calc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093944/361684)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution now (under the shower!)

Give the outer `DL` `display:block` and some padding to the left and right that add up to the margins and padding the `DT` and `DD`. Now the 100% of the `DL` are the basis for the 50%  of the inner elements. Now give these your desired margins and paddings. Until now it won't work as desired. Yet there's things still to come. Add up all the margins and paddings of the `DT` and the `DD`respectively. And give each a negative margin (the `DT` to the left and the `DD` to the right) so all the margins and paddings of them add up to zero/naught/niente/nada. E Voilà! Now you can have any combination of percentage you want, e.g. 30% - 70%.

```
dl {
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 20px;

}

/* the -15px in the margin is to compensate for the 5px in the margin and the 2 x 5px in the padding */
dt {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0px 5px 0 -15px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: yellow;
}
/* the -10px in the margin is to compensate for the 2 x 5px in the padding */
dd {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0px -10px 0 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/AADG7/

Comment: Nice solution. But speaking of dl/dt/dd I found to pretty hard to use. Try to the following markup:
    <dl>
    <dt>first<br/> name</dt>
    <dd><input /></dd>
    <dt>Last name</dt>
    <dd><input /></dd>
    </dl>

but, it's indeed isn't related the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure that each dt clears the previous alignment;

add

```
dt {
    clear:both;
}
```

to the css defined above

see http://jsfiddle.net/Nd2sH/

Answer (score 0):

I would use nested DIVs or spans, inside the  and  elements.  Right now, the 50% width is conflicting with the need for a padding or a margin.

Something like this would accomplish the same thing.

```
  <dt><div style="margin:5px;">first name</div></dt>
  <dd><div style="margin:5px;"><input /></div></dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only things about it you can do:

Use JavaScript to get the width of the `DL` and then calculate the width of the `DT` and the `DD` so that the `width` of these plus the `margin` and the `padding` add up to the 100% of the `DL`

Or set a fixed width for the first column and no width for the second

Or wrap the content of each `DT` and `DD` with a `DIV` and give this the `margin` and `padding`