# Is it possible to make a div 50px less than 100% in CSS3?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a `div` 50px less than 100% in pure CSS? I want the `<div>` to be only 50px less than 100%. I don't want any JavaScript.

Comment: @hakre - Your link is in CSS, and this is in CSS3.

Comment: how is CSS not CSS3 not CSS not CSS3 not CSS not ... ? If you ask explicitly for a CSS feature that has been formulated in version 3 only, please ask for it (not CSS generally - yes your question body differs from it's title here, so don't blame me ;) )

Comment: Well take a look at the body below the question title. You should use the body to make the CSS3 question explicit (and while we're talking please say if CSS3 or CSS3+)

Comment: @hakre: Agree with you - the only trace of "CSS3" in the original question was in the tags. If I had seen this question at the time it was asked I would have removed the tag, because indeed, CSS3 is CSS. It's not some entirely separate and different language, even though it extends far beyond what's possible in CSS2 (so-called "CSS"). But since edits have made it clear that this is a CSS3 question looking for a CSS3 answer, I guess we can leave it as it is...

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Yes you can. Without using the IE's `expression()`, you can do that in CSS3 by using [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc).

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Nw3yd/66/

This will make your life so much easier. It is currently supported in the 3 main browsers: Firefox, Google Chrome (WebKit), and IE9: http://caniuse.com/calc

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-calc

Comment: The problems are a) the question wasn't clear about width vs. height and b) the self-answer isn't the best answer. For width, sandeep's is better, for height, gilly3's. The OP's answer isn't supported on some significant browser statistics today. (IE7/8)

Comment: BTW: Non-prefixed version should go after the prefixed version, not before. See https://developer.mozilla.org/Writing_Forward_Compatible_Websites Also, in my experience, lots of calc() situations can be replaced by `box-sizing`.

Comment: "expression()" causes problems, because the browser recalculates the functions (inside the expressions) on each pixel of the mouse moviment, it impacts in processor uses. And in this case (with calc) this happens?

Comment: @bfrohs - For IE 6/7, you can use `expression()`.

Comment: I have to say that, for most websites, using `calc()` *for anything important* is a bad idea. The browser support is just not good enough.

Comment: Note that this question is specific to CSS3 and has a CSS3 specific answer, so it's not a dupe to others that were recommended which were only for prior versions.

Answer (score 159):

A **DIV** automatically takes its parent's width. So there is no need to define any `width`. Normally would simply write it like this:

```css
div{
    margin-right:50px;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw3yd/2/)

Comment: How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw3yd/3/) vs [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw3yd/4/)?

Comment: @Chango - [That](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw3yd/4/) is purely amazing when you resize the window.

Comment: @Chango may be that's you want to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/Nw3yd/6/

Comment: @sandeep In your example both div don't have the same size, the green one has a fixed size and the red one has what's left minus 200px. Your solution is great, but I found interesting that particular use case of Derek's answer.

Answer (score 37):

Another alternative is absolute positioning.

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 50px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw3yd/59/)

But, Sandeep's solution is the one you should usually use. Just
avoid overusing `float`.  This prevents elements from naturally filling their container.

Answer (score 7):

My solution works with and without `float: left`.

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

css:

```css
div {
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-clip: content-box; 
}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GB2ut/1/)

Compatibility:
 Firefox 3.6, Safari 5, Chrome 6, Opera 10, IE 9

Comment: The divs in your method are still occupying all the width of the screen, so if you put two of them you can't make them float on next to another.

Answer (score 4):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/bFFuH/)

Using display `block` and `margin`. `display:block` when not combined with a defined `height`/`width` will try to fill it's parent.

```
header {
    width:100%;
    background:#d0d0d0;
    height:100%;
}
h1 {
    display:block;
    border:#000 solid 1px;
    margin:0 50px 0 0;
    height:100px;
}
<header>
    <h1></h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score -4):

Yes we can do it by making

```
#custom_div{
 width:100%;
 margin-right:50px;
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: This is the same answer as sandeep's, besides `width:auto;`, which has no effect. Your answer does not add any value at all. Instead of posting your own version of sandeep's answer you should have upvoted sandeep's answer.