# Css to achieve {Width:100% -150px}

Tags: css, height

I've got a site with a side nav and I want the rest of the screen to be a filled with an image, the side nav is off the left and is 150px wide.

Ideally id like to set the full screen image at `width:100% -150px;` but I'm pretty sure this is not proper CSS.

Is there way to achieve the same effect ? I can't use `width:90%;` as on wider screens 150px would be more like 5% of the width rather than 10%.

Comment: in some browsers, this will work: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a div 50px less than 100% in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093943/is-it-possible-to-make-a-div-50px-less-than-100-in-css)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact - it is! (with css3)

```
width: calc(100% -150px);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 150px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 150px);
```

works, but only for the most modern browsers... [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

If you dont want to use this, you can use margin to create an offset: `margin-left:150px;`. This however needs a parent-element with 100% width and your image to be a block-level element (`display:block`).

Another option is to use [box-sizing](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing). This lets you choose another box-model which doesn't calculate margins and paddings into the element-width. This helps in some typical "i need 100% width - Xpx border" cases too.

In response to @BerkerYüceer's comment - you can also use dynamic values within the calc like following:

```
/* declare css variable */
--leftmargin:150px;

/* use the variable like following */
calc(100% - var(--leftmargin));
```

Comment: thanks, if id did this using the margin left method would i need to have the side nav sitting above the image using z-index ?

Comment: @sam take a look at phrogz demo, you don't need any zindex.

Comment: can you do something like calc(100% - margin-left)? asuming margin-left is dynamic...

Comment: @BerkerYüceer You can totally do this!! Either use a preprocessor (LESS/SASS) or native css variables - I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [calc()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) to get what you want using only CSS3.

```
div{
width: 100%;
width: calc(100% - 150px);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 150px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

You can see an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/masimao/2EkLv/)

Works fine in IE9, Firefox and Google Chrome.

Additional reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-calc

Answer (score 2):

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MY6Z9/

```css
#content { margin-left:150px }
```

Assuming that your `#content` item is a `display:block` element that, by default, will fill the available width.

---

If you want a single image to fill the width, instead of tiling, you can use a background image along with [`background-size`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) on modern browsers:

```css
#content {
  background:url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size:100% auto; 
}
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MY6Z9/5/

Answer (score 0):

For a non-`position:static` element you could try setting `right: 150px;`

Answer (score 0):

You may use a wrapping div around #image-full div to achieve this:

```
#image-wrapper
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    padding-right:150px;
}

#image-full
{
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(...);
    /* ... */
}

#navigation
{
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
}
```