# CSS value as mathematical expression

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway that I can write a css value as mathematical expression?
Example:

```
div{
    height: 50% + 30px;
    width: 40em - 5px;
   }
```

If there is, it would be perfect. 
**PS:** I don't want to do it with *JS* or *JQuery*.

Comment: I'm trying to make it for any kind of window size. If I plan to write it on js I should write both `.ready()` and `.resize()` functions which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can achieve this with css3 [calc()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc). Write like this:

```
div{
    width: 40%;
    width: -webkit-calc(40% - 5px);
    width: -moz-calc(40% - 5px);
    width: calc(40% - 5px);
    height:50%;
    height: -webkit-calc(50% + 50px);
    height: -moz-calc(50% + 50px);
    height: calc(50% + 50px);
    background: green;
    color: white;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/3QUw6/

Check this discussion for more [Is it possible to make a div 50px less than 100% in CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093943/is-it-possible-to-make-a-div-50px-less-than-100-in-css3/11094450#11094450)

Comment: But the question is why would you want to use this?

Comment: Plus, not compatible <IE8 or any mobile browser - http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: @Wex that's why i define CSS3 on it.

Comment: @Wex we already suggest Chrome for our users so there is no problem. Plus I explained why I don't prefer to use js above.

Comment: This... is... absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 3):

You can not do this with CSS, but you could (and much more) with a CSS preprocessor, like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or my favorite [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/). THe final output is plain old CSS, but it must be compiled first.

Comment: I didn't know that. Seems very useful.

Comment: The first that comes to my mind was less but, if the size of the element is dependent on the content then less would not be able guess the correct size, thus rendering invalid in some particular cases, other than that, it would be a perfect solution. But for this, CSS3 is better imho.

Answer (score 2):

Both `padding` and `margin` can be used to add to the dimensions of objects. I suggest you read up on the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
    width: 40em;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 15px 0; /* Top and bottom padding of 15px */ }

/* Block-level element will take up 100% of the 
  container width, minus {margin_right} + {marign_left} */
.wrapper > div { margin: 0 0 0 5px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [calc()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) function in CSS. Hopefully the support for this will increase in browsers.