# div px from center

Tags: html, css

I have a div width is 800px in the center aligned with:

```
  min-height:800px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
```

I have a div on the right of it which is fixed like:

```
  left:50%;
  padding-left:400px;
  position:fixed;
```

But now the div is over the main content.

So if there is a button in main content I can't click it because the fixed div is over it.

I have tried giving it a lower z-index, but if I do that I can't click the buttons on the side div.

Is it possible to give it a `margin left:50% + 400px;`
so I don't need padding?

Comment: can you give us a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: looks like you are doing some strange CSS, what is the motive behind it?

Comment: I have a main div with content, and besides the div is a fixed div so always in the screen with social media button, it looks like it is attached to the side of the div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change `padding-left` to `margin-left`:

```css
left: 50%;
margin-left: 400px;
position: fixed;
```

Or use [calc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093944/361684) in modern browsers:

```css
left: calc(50% + 400px);
position: fixed;
```

Comment: The first solution worked, Haha i should have known that. thx a ton i did some weard css in there trying to fix it.