# Css border-box for IE7 and IE6?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [box-sizing support in ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909667/box-sizing-support-in-ie7)

Is there any trick to use `box-sizing:border-box;` in IE6 and IE7?
Or at least in IE7..

Answer (score 1):

Yes certainly, you can use this for IE6, IE7

[**box-sizing-polyfill**](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill)

In your CSS

```
box-sizing: border-box;
*behavior: url('boxsizing.htc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to dissapoint you. It works from on Internet Explorer 8 and up, you gotta find a work arround. Most likely with widths and paddings...

[Article about box-sizing](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)