# IE7 - box-sizing not working even for fixed width element

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a div in my layout which has `box-sizing` property assigned to it with value `border-box`. It works good in other browsers but does not work in IE7. I have read that for fixed width elements, it works. The IE developer tool tells that `box-sizing` property is assigned correctly. The CSS code:

```
.item {
    width:360px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding:12px 24px;
    margin-bottom:24px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

It breaks the layout.

Comment: IE7 does not support `box-sizing` - period. IE7 does not even have developer tools. Where did you get that information from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909667/box-sizing-support-in-ie7

Comment: Already answered..this question is duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909667/box-sizing-support-in-ie7

Comment: @BoltClock I read it yesterday when I was searching the web for fix. If it does not support then why it does not show it in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately IE7 doesn't support `box-model: border-box` and uses the W3C content box model instead. There are a couple of options here - [use a polyfil](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill) or write specific IE7 rules in a conditional comment.

Comment: Content box model, not padding box model.