# Responsive design navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

---

- This is a responsive design.
- Logo is the ONLY fixed width element in here. Other element’s width should be depend by thiere content.
- Navigation item are uncountable. So No way to set a fixed width. (May be 3 or 4 menu items)
- Search element’s width should be depends with other elements. and streach to the maximum it can.
- Username can be very, so can’t defined a width in here. If username is longer, the element’s width is longer.

Tried few methods: 
* Make outer div as a display:table and every other element as display: table-cell.
* Define search's width by calculating with jquery window resize. But when click window resize button, it's width is not as it should be.

**Anyone got a idea about how to implement this navigation using pure CSS/ CSS3 or if not by jquery ?**

Appreciate your ideas, helps...

Comment: This looks like the most easiest question ever asked, But when you do you feel this is bit tricky... Anyone got an idea how to make search element 100% ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/6jXcz/1/

Scales perfectly fine horizontally and independent of number of navigation items.

**Explanation:** I used the "table" CSS rules and forced the `#search` to have a width of 100%. In order to prevent the logo (or any other elements) from getting "crushed", I used `white-space: nowrap` on the `#menu` and `min-width` on the `#logo`.

```
<div id="table">
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
        <ul id="navigation"><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul>
        <div id="search">
            <input type="text" name="search">
        </div>
        <div id="user">Username</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu {
    background: grey;
    line-height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-row;
}
#menu > * {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    height: 50px;
}
#logo {
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navigation li {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
#search {
    background: #aaa;
    width: 100%;
}
#search input {
    width: 98%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    height: 92%;
}
```

Comment: Wow !!! You are my hero <3 Tried this, but at some point I faild. Now I can check with this to find out what I did wrong in previously. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Glad I could help! Make sure to override `white-space` on the menu childs if you want wrapping text somewhere inside the menu.

Comment: @s-b Any way to make this IE7 compatible ?

Comment: @stackminu unfortunately, IE7 doesn't support CSS tables, so your best bet is to simulate that for IE7. Maybe something like http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to S.B.'s answer, I would change the `#search input` CSS to this to prevent resizing issues with the 98% width (you can see the padding to the right of the search box grows awkwardly on resizing on the original answer):

Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/6jXcz/2/

```
#search input {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;    
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Yes thats right, I add that part when I coded. And came here to mention that. Anddddddd... You commented that part. hehehehe... Thanks mate. :)

Comment: Any way to make this IE7 compatible ?

Comment: Though most web developers no longer support IE7 ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909667/box-sizing-support-in-ie7