# Disable warnings (ids selector) in linter-csslint on Atom?

Tags: css, atom-editor, linter

How to disable warnings in linter-csslint on Atom like iDs selector 
[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNFOs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.csslintrc` file in your project's directory as specified [here](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Command-line-interface#configuration-files). Inside the file, you can add this:

```
{
  "ignore": [
    "ids"
  ]
}
```

You can see the full list of rules [here](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Rules).

Comment: Thanks, .For each project a .csslintrc file in the directory? 
I really do not understand how to do it, in sublime text. Add a few lines of code and go

Comment: You could try adding a `.csslintrc` to your home `~` directory, although I haven't tried it. If that doesn't work, try opening an issue on the GitHub repo for `linter-csslint`. This is just my opinion, but I think it's good practice to include config files like this in your project so that if anyone else is also developing it's clear to them what your style guidelines are, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I could not solve the problem, 
Do you know how I can find the file `Brackets/brackets.json` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189103/how-to-ignore-specific-warnings-outputted-by-the-csslint-extension-for-brackets