# ATOM - CSSLINT ignore ids

Tags: css, html, atom-editor, csslint

Is there a way to make csslint in Atom ignore "ids", so I don't get the warning "Don't use IDs in selectors"?

Edit: My question was identified as a possible duplicate of "[Disable warnings (ids selector) in linter-csslint on Atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875427/disable-warnings-ids-selector-in-linter-csslint-on-atom)", but I mentioned in my own answer that I could not understand how to make the process to solve my problem. I ended up finding out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable warnings (ids selector) in linter-csslint on Atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875427/disable-warnings-ids-selector-in-linter-csslint-on-atom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, guys, I ended up discovering how to do that. The other questions similar to mine did solve the problem, but they were not so clear TO ME on how to make the solution work. If you guys go to github "https://github.com/ebednarz/csslintrc/blob/master/.csslintrc", there are some lines to ignore the elements. What wasn't that clear to me was "ok, what should I do with it?".

So you have two options (I use Windows). You either create a file in Atom or command line called ".csslintrc" and place it INSIDE THE FOLDER OF THE PROJECT you are working on OR you can place this file in your USER FOLDER IN WINDOWS. Like, "C:\Users\yourUserName". If you put it there, all the projects will use this file.