# What can i use instead of css box-sizing?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have the following `html` and `css` codes. I don't want to use `box-sizing:border-box` which is not supported in some browsers like IE(6-7), how may I solve my problem with `css` in order to still have the same orders of the `div`s? I want the gaps between the floated divs remain the same.

```css
div[class="clmn"]{
border:solid .1em ;
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
width:33.13%;
padding:0.2em;
margin:.1%;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

div[id="div0"]{
background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.1);
border:solid 1px red;
overflow:auto;

}

#div1{
float:left;
}

#div2{
float:right;
}

#div3{
float:right;
}

#div4, #div00{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="div00" class="clmn"> This is div 00</div>
<div id="div0">
<div id="div1" class="clmn"> This is div 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="clmn"> This is div 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="clmn"> This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3.This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3.This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3.This is div 3</div>

</div>
<div id="div4" class="clmn"> This is div 4</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE 7 is so old it won't run on any operating system for which there are security updates. You should encourage people to upgrade systems running it instead of pandering to them.

Comment: Do you realy want to support IE 6-7?

Comment: Bottom line: if you absolutely have to support IE7, then you'll need to use the techniques that were in common use back at the time of IE7, because that's what works. In this case, that probably means adding extra layers of `<div>` elements to give you more fine grained control over the boxes. But frankly, box-sizing is going to be least of your problems.

Comment: Yes I want to. Because my friends are old. They like antiques.

Comment: https://www.matrixgroup.net/snackoclock/2012/08/simple-box-sizing-border-box-fallback-for-ie/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909667/box-sizing-support-in-ie7/10978314

Comment: get a new jobb/client... not even joking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [box-sizing support in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909667/box-sizing-support-in-ie7)

Answer (score 0):

I found the polyfill for **box-sizing:border-box** which can help you to solve your issue for IE 7 browser.

You can download the polyfill from the link below.

[A CSS box-sizing: border-box polyfill for IE 6/7](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill)

You need to include it after this line **box-sizing: border-box** in your CSS code.

```
box-sizing: border-box; *behavior: url(/scripts/boxsizing.htc);
```

Your modified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div[class="clmn"]{
border:solid .1em ;
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
width:33.13%;
padding:0.2em;
margin:.1%;
box-sizing:border-box;
*behavior: url(/boxsizing.htc); /*User need to modify the URL here...*/
}

div[id="div0"]{
background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.1);
border:solid 1px red;
overflow:auto;

}

#div1{
float:left;
}

#div2{
float:right;
}

#div3{
float:right;
}

#div4, #div00{
width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div00" class="clmn"> This is div 00</div>
<div id="div0">
<div id="div1" class="clmn"> This is div 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="clmn"> This is div 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="clmn"> This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3.This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3.This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3. This is div 3.This is div 3</div>

</div>
<div id="div4" class="clmn"> This is div 4</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output with IE 7 document mode in IE 11 browser:

[image]

**Note: The IE 7 browser was out of support a long time ago. It is not recommended to use IE 7 browser. I suggest you use the latest Microsoft browsers. If you are not available to upgrade to the latest Microsoft browser then at least move to IE 11 browser.**